# how to stream google cloud storage file to local file

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a large file (75MB+) that I want to download from google cloud storage and write to a local file on a mobile device.  Application is written in Flutter/Dart.  Using the following code snippet: (all the authorization is working correctly.)

```dart
var storage = new StorageApi(http_client);
storage.objects
            .get(
              'bucket',
              'file.ext',
            )
            .asStream()
            .cast<List<int>>()
            .pipe(outFile.openWrite());
```

This results in the error
`[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Object' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>' in type cast`

If the `.cast<List<int>>()` is removed, the error is 
`error type '_ControllerStream<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<List<int>>' of 'stream'`

The file sizes seem to big to write to memory, so I have focused on using `asStream()`.

Thank you,

Comment: Have you looked at the example in https://github.com/dart-lang/gcloud?  They seem to do things slightly differently, but are accomplishing exactly what you are describing.